# Magento : how to display items in cart in the order they were added

Tags: magento-1.6

I want to display the items in cart in the order they were added. But i am unable to find the code which sets the quote item collection.

in my cart phtml file i am using 
$allItems = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();

to get all the items.

How do i sort the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution 
put the `setOrder('updated_at','desc')` in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php
in file getItemsCollection function to sort the collection.

```
public function getItemsCollection($useCache = true)
    {
        if (is_null($this->_items)) {
            $this->_items = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()**->setOrder('updated_at','desc');**
            $this->_items->setQuote($this);
        }
        return $this->_items;
    }
```